# Retrieving div contents from a php page and posting to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in a page called; `products.php` whose details I'd like to send to the database including the contents of `class='stars'` exactly as is in its HTML format, I thought the code in the form action; `review.php`  would solve it but I'm met by an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/TUTP/review.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/TUTP/review.php on line 8` . What is the best way of retrieving the div star and sending it to my database the way I'm doing with the contents of the input?

```
  <?php 

    echo "
        <form action='reviews.php' method='POST'>
                    <div class='stars'>
                            <i class='fas fa-star star'></i>
                            <i class='fas fa-star star'></i>
                            <i class='fas fa-star star'></i>
                            <i class='fas fa-star star'></i>
                            <i class='fas fa-star star'></i>    
                        </div>
                    <input class='reviewIn' type='text' name='reviewPost' placeholder='Enter review'>
                    <button type='submit' name='submitR'>POST</button>
                </form>";


<!-- reviews.php -->
<?php  
    

    if (isset($_POST['submitR'])) {

        include_once "db.php";

        $html = file_get_html('product.php');

        $stars = $html->find('.stars');

        $title=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['title']);

        $reviewPost = $_POST['reviewPost'];

        echo $html;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                        echo "SQL statement failed 1!";

                }else{

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);


            $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews(reviewsField,itemName,starRating) VALUES (?,?,?);";

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                        echo "SQL statement failed 2!";

            }else{

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$reviewPost,$title,$stars);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            

                    }
                  }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need escape variables when using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download PHP HTML Dom parser and include it.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('product.php');
```

[php html dom parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. And is there a way to get raw html code?